# Unexpected error in laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, laravel

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
>
> 1/1
>       FatalErrorException in User.php line 9:
>       Trait 'App\Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable' not found
>       in User.php line 9

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
}
I am using laravel 5.2 version
```

Comment: show us your USer.php code

Answer (score 1):

`\App` is your default first namespace. `\Illuminate` is its own. Change instances of `Illuminate` to `\Illuminate` and it should resolve the problem.

Comment: thanks it's working now